# No refresh or page reload using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have an Ajax request in my Rails 4 app, but once the button is clicked it reloads the entire page. How can I keep that from happening? The page is cached so I cannot simply add a link_to or button_to. Thanks in advance.

listing_collection.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".listcollect").on("click", function(){
      var listID = this.id;
        $.ajax({
          method: "GET",
          url: "/listing_collections/:id/listcollect",
          success: function(result) {
            var arrLen = result.length
            var $ul = $("<ul></ul>")
            for (var i = 0; i<arrLen; i++){
                var $li = $("<li></li>");
                var $a = $("<a></a>");
                $a.attr("href", "/listings/" + listID + "/add_to_collection?listing="+listID+"$amp;listing_collection_id="+result[i]["id"]+"&amp;listing_id="+listID)
                $a.text(result[i]["name"])
                $li.append($a)
                $(this).next().append($li)
            }
          }.bind(this)
        })
    });
});
```

This is the button:

```
<div class="btn-group listcollect-wrapper">
    <button class="listcollect button btn-blue-white btn-2x dropdown-toggle" data-toggle='dropdown' type="button" id=<%= listing.id %>>Add to Listing Collection <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class='dropdown-menu'>

    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Did you create that button with a `button_to` helper?

Comment: I didn't. It's a cached page so a simple button_to or link_to won't work...or so I was led to believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My two cents
The dom with this class `.listcollect` is a button of type submit i.e `button type="submit"`

You can either use `button type = "button"` or use

```
event.preventDefault()

$(".listcollect").on("click", function(){
      event.preventDefault()
    // Rest of code

})
```

Comment: I already have button type button. I also tried to add the preventDefault and that didn't work.

Comment: So I changed the button to a submit and added the preventDefault, and it still reload the entire page.

Answer (score 0):

It's because this is the default behaviour of the anchor tag. As suggested you can either change the control type to something like button or override the default behaviour like so:

```
$(".listcollect").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".listcollect").on("click", function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();

      var listID = this.id;
        $.ajax({
          method: "GET",
          url: "/listing_collections/:id/listcollect",
          success: function(result) {
            var arrLen = result.length
            var $ul = $("<ul></ul>")
            for (var i = 0; i<arrLen; i++){
                var $li = $("<li></li>");
                var $a = $("<a></a>");
                $a.attr("href", "/listings/" + listID + "/add_to_collection?listing="+listID+"$amp;listing_collection_id="+result[i]["id"]+"&amp;listing_id="+listID)
                $a.text(result[i]["name"])
                $li.append($a)
                $(this).next().append($li)
            }
          }.bind(this)
        })
    });
});
```

I have added e.preventDefault() that prevents the browser to handle the the click by default and e.stopPropagation() that disable the propagation of the click event to the containers of your control, in case they have listener too.

Comment: That didn't work for me. The dropdown no longer works.